# Sorting a column in splunk by month

Tags: sorting, splunk, monitor

I am new to splunk, I wrote a query and it working fine except the column that contains month and year is sorted with alphabetical order means April,Feb,Jan. How can I sort in chronological order like Jan,Feb,march

This is my code

```
dedup EnvelopID 
| stats count by ReportPeriod EnvelopStatus "Template10 TemplateName Region Country 
| addcoltotals 
| eval EnvelopStatus (case EnvelopStatus "SUBMITTERSIGNED "PENDINGAPPROVAL" EnvelopStatus = "APPROVERAPPROVED", "PENDINGAPPROVAL", EnvelopStatus = "SUBMITTERREJECTED","REJECTED", EnvelopStatus = APPROVERREJECTED", "REJECTED" EnvelopStatus = "CREATED","CREATED", EnvelopStatus "COMPLETED", "COMPLETED", EnvelopStatus "VOIDED", "VOIDED")
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/How-to-sort-data-in-chronological-order-by-month-not/m-p/142279), [this one](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/How-to-chart-data-by-month-with-sorting-order/m-p/585394) or [this](https://community.splunk.com/t5/Splunk-Search/How-to-sort-data-in-chronological-order-by-month-not/m-p/368705) answer your question ?

Comment: What does the data look like? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the format of the values of `ReportPeriod`?  Also, it looks like your comma and = keys are not working well.

Answer (score 0):

Splunk only does lexicographical sorting so "Feb" always comes before "Jan" and so on.  To override that, associate an integer with each month and sort by integer.

````
<<your search>>
| eval sorter = case(month="Jan",1, month="Feb",2, month="Mar",3, month="Apr",4,
                     month="May",5, month="Jun",6, month="Jul",7, month="Aug",8
                     month="Sep",9, month="Oct", 10, month="Nov", 11, month="Dec", 12, 1==1,99)
| sort + sorter
``` Discard the sorter ```
| fields - sorter
````